# Creating a Column Graph using Highcharter in R

Tags: shiny, r-highcharter

I am having trouble creating an interactive column chart in R using highcharter. Here is the code that I am trying to work with:

```
library(highcharter)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(extrafontdb)
testdata<-read.table("Matrix_Mean_sym.txt", header=TRUE)
testdata2<-t(testdata)
testdatase<-read.table("Matrix_SE_sym.txt", header=TRUE)
testdatase2<-t(testdatase)

ui<-dashboardPage(...
tabItem(tabName = "graph",
                           fluidRow(
                             box(title= "Gene Selection",
                                 selectizeInput(inputId = "gene", "Gene Symbol:", 
                                                choices = colnames(testdata2), 
                                                selected="CD8A", 
                                                options = NULL,
                                                multiple = FALSE)),
                             box(title= "Graph of Gene Expression",
                                 highchartOutput("genePlot"))
                           ))
server<- function(input, output) {
  output$genePlot <- {
   renderHighchart({
    require(input$gene)
  highchart() %>%
    hc_add_series(data = list(testdata2[, input$gene]), type="column") %>%
    hc_xAxis(categories = c('CD14+', 
                            'CD19+',
                            'CD4+',
                            'CD56+',
                            'CD8+',
                            'Neutrophils',
                            'nRBCs',
                            'WB')) %>%
    hc_title(text= "Graph of Gene Expression")      
})}
```

I know I do not provide a working dataset, but this is from a 140904 element matrix. The error that shows up every time I run this code is:
Warning in if (!loaded) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
c("Loading required package: $", "Loading required package: input", "Loading required package: gene")
Failed with error:  ‘'package' must be of length 1’
Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported, and named vectors will be translated into arrays instead of objects. If you want JSON object output, please use a named list instead. See ?toJSON.
 Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How `testdata` looks like? Can you provide some sample of you data? It would be easier to help you out.

Comment: The dataset I am using is a huge dataset. For examples sake, the rownames are:  CD14+ CD19+ CD4+ CD56+ CD8+ Neutrophils nRBCs WB
The column names are the specific genes I am studying. These are the variables I am trying to call when graphing the graph. I am new to Stack Overflow so I do not know how to link datasets.

Comment: This answer has been resolved. All I had to do was insert drop=FALSE when calling my column data.